# Procedural/Value Depending Animation/Keyframe Start

Tags: animation, materials, drivers

I am wondering if there is a way to set the keyframes in shader editor or graph editor depending on attributes or values.

For example you have a cube and when it turns red the keyframe animation starts.

This would be useful to have a lot more flexibility in animations, for example when you control the red value through an x coordinate driver.

Would Appreciate any help.

Comment: isn't this exactly what drivers are doing? you drive/change values depending on other values?

Comment: but you cant set drivers on the position of keyframes can you? Maybe there is a way that I dont know.

Comment: No, but what is a keyframe? Or 2 keyframes? Just a formula. And this is what drivers do. Executing formulas.

Comment: But I dont want to use the frames as drivers, I want to change the position of the frames depending on values.